# DIgitalOcean droplets cpu usage is high with couple of users online

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, digital-ocean, nginx-reverse-proxy

We are proxing video streaming through nodejs. Cant tell if thats normal or not, but basically we tested by launching 10 chrome windows with our website and on all of them played HD videos which are streaming using hls player from 3rd party apis.

This is the node express servers GET which streams video back to UI:

```
app.get('/getVideo', (req, res) => {

  const options = {
    url: req.query.url
  }

  const urlRequest = request(options).on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Error:', err)
  })

  req.pipe(urlRequest).pipe(res)
})
```

Now from seeing the process graph we noticed that from steady 1-3% cpu usage jumped to 14% and thats with only 10 "users". That makes no sense as it means the website with the basic DigitalOcean droplet can handle no more than 50 users until the website crashes upon itself.

Are we missing something here or is that a normal nodejs performance?

Droplet specs:

- 1 GB / 1 CPU
- 25 GB SSD Disk
- 1000 GB transfer
- Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64

Comment: Are you sure that the node instance is using that cpu? Also please share the specs of your droplet.

Comment: There is nothing else what could be using this. All other resources are directly fetched from 3rd party apis, only video streaming which is proxied. Updated question with droplet specs